# Parameterised array using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

How to define numpy array as 
`X = numpy.array([x , x*x , x*x*x ,... ]`
such that output is **[2,4,8,..] when x=2**, 
where **x** is a local variable in python.

Comment: `2**np.arange(32)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Triangles! :D

```
>>> 2**np.arange(30)

array([        1,         2,         4,         8,        16,        32,
              64,       128,       256,       512,      1024,      2048,
            4096,      8192,     16384,     32768,     65536,    131072,
          262144,    524288,   1048576,   2097152,   4194304,   8388608,
        16777216,  33554432,  67108864, 134217728, 268435456, 536870912])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import numpy as np
power = [i + 1 for i in range(10)]
np.power(2, power)
```

In the above code, power is a list having values 1 to 10. In the `np.power()` step, 2 is being raised to the power as per list element. The output of the above code is

```
array([   2,    4,    8,   16,   32,   64,  128,  256,  512, 1024])
```

The range 10 can be changed as per requirement.